# Use only one useState hook in (filtered) Search list

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-state

In `ArticlePage.js`, in my current setup [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-wind-hhphi), I use multiple `useState()` hooks to render and filter my Posts list:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);
```

I was wondering, refactoring and optimizing this code, could I also only have (instead of both above)?:

```
const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);
```

I want the component only to re-render:

- if amount of Posts change
- if typed value in Search input change

I think my setup is quit ok, but I am wondering if I can improve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace

```
const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);
```

with

```
const filteredPosts = useMemo(
    () => posts.filter((post) => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())),
    [search, posts]
);
```

and remove

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(
      posts.filter((post) => {
        return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
      })
    );
  }, [search, posts]);
```